# How to sort items by date inside a sitecore query?

Tags: sxa, querybuilder

I am trying to sort items inside a query under a variant. I used

> +template:{00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000};+sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;+sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage;sort:FromDate

It returns a rendering error. When I sort by Title instead of date, it works fine. Is there a way to sort by a date field inside this query?

Comment: Can you add the query that's used when you sort by `Title` instead?

Comment: I just change the field name for Sort
+template:{00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000};+sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;+sxa:ExcludeCurrentPage;sort:Title

Comment: Can you check the query in the search logs? Try that query in the solr/azure search admin..